# If the page is blank, how to write warning message in log file while compiling

Tags: blank-page

If the page is blank, how to write warning message in log file while compiling?

Could somebody give some solution.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

First Page

\newpage\hfill\\

%Blank page

\newpage

Last Page

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.``

Comment: Hai Alessandro Cuttin, I have added sample coding.

Comment: I don't get the need of a warning, if the code does _exactly_ what you tell him to do. You know in advance the behavior of the output. 
Warnings are meant for  the "you wanted this, but I can do at best that" kind of situations; when the behavior of the output is not exactly what you expected (like overfull boxes, and so on).
My best guess is that, If you want a warning issued, that implies looking at the inner workings of the article class, which you will then have to patch yourself.

Comment: Besides, empty pages are included by default in certain situations: when you use the `openright` option, or when you use the `book` class.